# Discouraged by advisor to take courses, is there a way to navigate through this situation?

Tags: advisor, productivity, learning

Graduate schools in North America usually have a required number of courses that you need to pass. Afterwards, the school is usually pretty flexible at the student taking more courses (and it is often free of charge), but it is another story with advisor/PI/supervisor.

After I passed my courses, I have been either explicitly or implicitly reminded by my advisor that I should not take more courses. None of any other graduate students are taking courses either in some sort of tacit acknowledgement. Taking courses takes away time from research and performing badly could cause serious problems, so it is understandable.

However, I find that after a year or two of not taking any courses, I feel less mentally "sharp". And sometimes I say to myself "I wish I had taken information theory/blackhole physics/statistical methods!" because I think they could open up more research ideas and plus some subjects are just hard when studied on your own. Finally, taking courses open up more employment opportunities, either through TAship or working in industry. I get the feeling that some/many advisors in academia (such as mine) are fairly indifferent about transitioning from graduate school to industry and do not appreciate the importance of courses/technical skills to these future opportunities.

Has anyone been able to successfully navigate through this dilemma? There are pro and con to each side of the argument and I could't make a move in fear of jeopardizing my relationship with my advisor.

Comment: _I say to myself "I wish I had taken information theory/blackhole physics/statistical methods!" because I think they could open up more research ideas_ Study them alone. That can be _brutally hard_, but you'll learn more and become more _mentally "sharp"._

Comment: _taking courses open up more employment opportunities_, is there evidence to support that?

Comment: @user2768 Yes, but sometimes guided studies of condensed material could be beneficial.

Comment: _I get the feeling that some/many advisors in academia (such as mine) are fairly indifferent about transitioning from graduate school to industry_ I suspect advisors are well aware that must students transition, they're just unaware how to transition or lack knowledge of industry, because it doesn't interest them

Comment: @user2768 Yes. The algorithm and machine learning courses are always filled to their maximum capacity. It is well known that these courses are populated by industry driven students.\

Comment: Right, but do they actually open up employment opportunities? Does taking a course make you more eligible for a position? I seriously doubt that, especially as it takes time away from research, which is surely the primary reason you'd be offered a position. As you've said, _Taking courses takes away time from research_.

Comment: Ultimately, I'd recommend finishing your PhD as fast as possible, that gets you to the next step in your career. (I'll stop commenting, because this is turning into a chat, for which comments are not designed.)

Comment: Whoever is paying your salary will probably be on the hook for the tuition for whatever class you want to take. I can't say anyone will be happy about paying to to take an expensive class they also have to pay for and know you don't need.

Comment: What are they going to do if you take a course? Fire you? Cut your funding? I would do it anyway and let them b1txh. I'm perfectly happy to quit my PhD program at any time though. One of the only reasons a PhD isn't a total economic loss is the free tuition, which means courses.

Comment: @FourierFlux - many moons ago, when I passed my qualifying exam, my tuition status was changed. Actually taking courses was no longer allowed (except for the 'thesis research' 'course'). Turns out under the accounting system, the department had to lay our real money to take courses and were happy to do it for the required courses, but would not do it for non-required courses.

Comment: «I wish I had taken information theory/blackhole physics/statistical methods!» you may be glad to recognize this lacuna as soon as possible; it shall be _your_ trigger to acquire this knowledge.

Comment: If industry relevance is your concern, the problem might be smaller than you think, as you can safely remove information theory and black hole physics from your list.

Comment: How can you feel less sharp? I mean your research should be more challenging and teaching you more in depth than any module you could take. Are you afraid of putting in more work for research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I finished course work I found that what I really missed about them was discussing the ideas from the courses with fellow graduate students. What filled in the gap for me was an informal logic and foundations seminar that another grad student had created. We would meet about once a week at lunch time, discussing articles, books, and occasionally each other's research. It was a nice way to avoid becoming narrowly focused on your own research topic, learn about things of broader interest, and keep an active sense of community. At the same time, it wasn't very time-consuming so it was never a major distraction from our actual research. Perhaps something like that could work for you. If there isn't already something like that in your department, you could always take the initiative and organize one.

Comment: This is a great answer. An advanced PhD student is somewhere between a student and a professor; students take courses, professors do not, but professors still (ideally) learn new things, so try doing this the way that professors do.

Answer (score 28):

[Audit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/what-does-auditing-a-course-mean) the courses that you like, i.e., take them without receiving a grade/credit for it. You might not even need to formally audit courses, most professors will let you informally audit them. But as mentioned by others, research takes priority.

Comment: I did this a few times, and it must be said that few people auditing a course "for fun" will be there by the end of the course. Meetings with the advisor and research always seem to get in the way.

Answer (score 16):

You should talk to your advisor about *why* you want to take more courses, and discuss which one-or-two would contribute to your development as a PhD student.

Your advisor is correct in the sense that it is easy to spend too much time taking courses for interest, and you need to focus on your research. Also, to some extent you should be able to study the material without a teacher now.

On the other hand, your advisor may have a different idea from you about what you are aiming to achieve by doing a PhD. It is certainly possible that they do not think enough about being in a position to transition to industry.

Things that are not of some reasonable use to your studies you should do in your own time. On the other hand, at least in the UK it is recognised that some time (about 10 days per year) should reasonably be spent on career-building CPD.

Comment: What does CPD stand for? Career/professional development?

Comment: @llama Usually "continuing professional development".

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are getting a PhD:  Your advisor is correct.  Taking courses is not the purpose of a PhD.  A PhD is a research degree, and PhD students should do research.  If you want to take courses, you should be enrolled in a course-based degree.

Comment: In my time, going to academia was about education. I find the formulation "Taking courses is not the purpose of a PhD" a bit misleading. I think the learning process into breadth does not stop with entering a PhD programme. Perhaps better to say "Taking credit-relevant courses is not the purpose of a PhD". I agree with below answer that auditing may be the right way to approach this situation.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Learning is certainly an important part of a PhD, but course based learning is not important to PhD programs.  Doing research is the primary vehicle for learning.  In many countries, PhD students take zero courses.

Comment: "In many countries" - such as? In Germany, some time ago, it was perfectly normal for PhD students to attend advanced courses and seminars. I have no idea how it changed after the transition to the BSc/MSc system (Bologna). Doing research is "learning in depth". Going to courses/seminars is "learning in breadth" and I believe education consists of both.

Comment: Certainly, when I took my Ph.D. (1999-2004, in the UK), "zero courses" was the norm.  But that had changed dramatically by 2008; ISTR the reason it changed was because government got on the universities' backs about the (perceived) lack of transferable skills of Ph.D. graduates, although I can't find any documentary evidence of that now.

Comment: At some point in one's research career, you have to be able to teach yourself new things. And, the only way to learn how to do that is, well, by teaching yourself. And during your PhD is the time to do that because you have more time and fewer expectations that you will be up to speed by next week. So, I fully agree. Time to start learning how to learn on one's own.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs The French system formalizes training in your core domain toward the PhD thesis _plus_ mandatory classes (e.g., research ethics, interdisciplinary courses across different working groups) and continuing seminaries that you are not only the co-worker of a PI, but member of an école doctorale / Doctoral school [example Bordeaux](https://ed-svs.u-bordeaux.fr/en/Training-courses).  And right in the first week I had to enroll in additional lectures and lab classes to learn about one of the techniques to be used as soon as possible, exam included.

Comment: @DanielHatton I started mine in 2009 also in the UK and opted to take a couple of graduate level courses and one masters level (as a refresher given a few years since my first degree).  Other postgrads at the same time had a fairly high required course load in the first year.  My current experience as a postdoc is that the picture is similar - DTC (doctoral training centre) students have to take courses, others are usually permitted or encouraged, at least up to a point (and I've even been welcomed onto one as a postdoc)

Comment: I tracked down the record of the UK government leaning on British Universities to introduce course-type elements to the Ph.D.: it was recommendation 4.2 of the [Roberts Review](https://dera.ioe.ac.uk/4511/).

Comment: More to the point, if you're hoping to be awarded a PhD and you remain incapable of teaching yourself the material (ie: you still require a course and an instructor to assimilate new information) then it becomes difficult to justify awarding a degree that, effectively, certifies that the individual in question has demonstrated the ability to perform independent learning and research.

Answer (score 5):

After I passed my qualifying exams and passed enough classes to get over that hurdle, I took additional courses pass/fail or credit/no-credit (with the consent of the instructor) where it was clear I could pass or get credit without it impacting my workload too much. I took a lot of courses this way and learned a lot. My advisor encouraged it. It also helped him out if the course he was teaching was shy a few people, he could ask me to register, too, if I hadn't taken it for credit already. I could have taken courses outside my area, but I mostly doubled down on topics that would reinforce my knowledge and understanding of my research: mathematical underpinnings, practical underpinnings, etc. It helped make sure that I came into campus every day and did work, went to meetings, and stopped by the office/lab.

I usually didn't take more than one course per semester this way in order to try to keep my workload sane and to be sure I was making progress on my research with the rest of my time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want make an value argument that appeals to the research university's historical context and you have "enlightenment ideals", maybe appeal to [Lehr und Lernfreiheit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humboldtian_model_of_higher_education).

Probably someone could cite Weber / Foucault for evidence that enlightenment ideals are "problematic". Indeed if your advisor is hip they might also think that Lehr und Lernfreiheit is bullshit.

Regardless, I would like to see more Ph.D. students (in scientific fields in N. America who are being advised against taking courses in favor of doing research) ease up and just:

0. read along with courses they're into,
1. interrogate folks enrolled in courses they're into about the content of lectures they maybe had to miss (due to research obligations, administrivia, CS dept auditing policies, etc.);
2. just be present for courses they're into (usually oral consent from the lecturer will do, he/she might even be flattered, and won't even have to worry about assessing/grading your work!);
3. be honest about what they're doing (if it's safe) with their advisor (e.g., misbehave and own it) and their peers (invite them to audit with you);
4. go rogue (if it's safe) or just formally withdraw from the program to do what they want (e.g., doing research or building things or learning, but without any cognitive dissonance owing to the fact that "they are scared they *should* be ostracized from the group");
5. own the privilege of their choices and represent them to other Ph.D. students (e.g., if someone really needs statistical methods, they *need statistical methods*!).

Comment: I’m pretty sure you don’t mean “castigate” there. Maybe “interrogate”, but even that’s a bit harsh for the situation.